# Filter for rows that start with a number stored in a vector of numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stringr

I would like to filter a data frame by checking to see if a column starts with a number that is also stored in a numeric vector.

For example, consider the below data frame, with columns `Comment`and `Comment.Id`:

```
Comment         | Comment.Id
This comment    | 34_1_1_1
That comment    | 24
Another comment | 54_1_1
Please comment  | 234
More comments   | 13_1_1
Many comments   | 12
Comment again   | 119_1_1
```

And the following vector `num`:

```
num <- c(34, 54, 234, 13, 119)
```

I would like to look through the `Comment.Id` column, and if a comment Id starts with a number that is contained in the `num` vector, then filter for that row.

The resulting data frame would look like this:

```
Comment         | Comment.Id
This comment    | 34_1_1_1
Another comment | 54_1_1
Please comment  | 234
More comments   | 13_1_1
Comment again   | 119_1_1
```

I am using the R language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- structure(list(Comment = c("This comment", "That comment", "Another comment", 
"Please comment", "More comments", "Many comments", "Comment again"
), Comment.Id = c("34_1_1_1", "24", "54_1_1", "234", "13_1_1", 
"12", "119_1_1")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

num <- c(34, 54, 234, 13, 119)
```

How about:

```
## str_extract() gets the first substring matching the REGEX pattern
df[stringr::str_extract(df$Comment.Id, "[0-9]+") %in% num, ]
#           Comment Comment.Id
#1 This comment       34_1_1_1
#3 Another comment      54_1_1
#4 Please comment          234
#5 More comments        13_1_1
#7 Comment again       119_1_1
```

Or in `dplyr` syntax:

```
df %>% filter(str_extract(Comment.Id, "[0-9]+") %in% num)
```

Or as [Sotos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5635580) commented, without any packages we can use:

```
## here, sub() removes all stuff after the first '_'
df[sub('_.*', '', df$Comment.Id) %in% num, ]

## R's native forward pipe operator, since R 4.1.0
df |> subset(sub('_.*', '', df$Comment.Id) %in% num)
```

---

**Note:**

I did not put an `as.numeric()` outside `sub` or `str_extract`, as the code works without it. But still, it is good practice to do this explicit type conversion.